# What is happening to my Avocado tree? The leaves turned yellow and then started to turn brown

Tags: diagnosis, avocado

I have planted an avocado seed in water using toothpicks (About 1/3 submerged in the water. It was growing well, and started growing nice green leaves. But in the past 2 weeks the leaves started turning yellow and then the leaves started dying/turning brown and dry. It doesn't seem to affect my 2 other seeds in the same situation (yet?). What could be the cause? Or is it normal at that stage? I already cut one leave off. (The holes in the leaves were done by an insect).

[image: Leaves]

[image: The roots have something white attached to it Possibly calcium from the water?]

Comment: ...and **how long** has it been in water, with the only available nutrients being what was stored in the seed?

Comment: Around 1 and a half months. I changed the water every 2-3 days. The sources I read online stated that one shouldn't fertilise it the first couple months as the seed was supposedly enough. I planned to plant it into a pot this or next week though.

Comment: I can see in the picture it's also getting direct sun-light. Has that bothered it before? Remember that in water, it can get light, oxygen and water, but on soil it will also get the nutrient from the soil!

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on growing these from seed!  Well done so far.

The roots are used to pull water and oxygen up. With it being submerged it will not be able to get the oxygen.  You can see a similar effect with potted plants when they get root rot.

Your idea to put the seed in a pot is a good idea. I would do it right away and see if that helps.   Best of luck!